# in email mutipart message body (with attachment) is comming as plain text instead html format

Tags: android, jsoup, jakarta-mail, multipart

I am writing an email client android app. In it, I am using `JavaMail`. While reading emails from server everything is coming properly except for a few mails which have attachments. In those cases the email body is coming as plain text instead of HTML format.

My code is as follows:

```java
String str; //=bodyPart.toString();//(bodyPart.getContent());
if (bodyPart instanceof Part) {
   if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof String) {
       str = bodyPart.getContent().toString();
   }
   else {
       MimeMultipart mimeMultipart = (MimeMultipart) bodyPart.getContent();
       str = getTextFromMimeMultipart(mimeMultipart);
   }
}
else
   str = bodyPart.getContent().toString();

//
//*****************************
//

private String getTextFromMimeMultipart(MimeMultipart mimeMultipart)  throws MessagingException, IOException {
   String result = "";
   int count = mimeMultipart.getCount();
   for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
       BodyPart bodyPart = mimeMultipart.getBodyPart(i);
       if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/plain")) {
           result = result + "\n" + bodyPart.getContent();
           break; // without break same text appears twice in my tests
       }
       else if (bodyPart.isMimeType("text/html")) {
           String html = (String) bodyPart.getContent();
           result = result + "\n" + Jsoup.parse(html).text();//html;// + org.Jsoup.parse(html).text();
       }
       else if (bodyPart.getContent() instanceof MimeMultipart) {
           result = result + getTextFromMimeMultipart((MimeMultipart)bodyPart.getContent());
       }
   }
   return result;
}
```

Comment: `plain text` instead of `plain text`?

Comment: instead of Html format

Comment: There will be both text/plain and text/html.

Comment: How to get text/html content.